# workflow on all documents in a document set

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

Using SharePoint Designer 2010, I was wandering if it is possible to some how retrieve all of the documents inside a document set?  I eventually want a workflow to run against all of these documents but I can't seem to figure out how I would go about retrieving them first.

Comment: How do you want to trigger the workflow? If it's something periodic (like dayly, weekly etc.) you could have a retention stage on the document set. It would fire the workflow once per item per period. You wouldn't have one workflow dealing with multiple items, but rather multiple workflows dealing with one item each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few limitations with SharePoint Designer 2010 that make it impossible to do this without resorting to a custom workflow action developed in Visual Studio:

- no ability to list of documents in a document set
- no ability to loop in SharePoint Designer 2010
- no ability to start a workflow from a workflow

All of these limitations can be mitigated with a little code in a custom action, but there is absolutely no way to do this with the standard out-of-box workflow actions.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of, Thanks for your response Chris.

Comment: If you don't want to develop the code yourself, try the Harepoint Workflow Scheduler. Works great for me in a similar scenario.

Comment: @teylyn, Harepoint Workflow Scheduler do not provide feature to list items\documents in specifyied folder\document set.

Comment: @AlexanderUlmaskulov HarePoint Workflow Scheduler works on all items you can return with a CAML query.

Comment: @teylin When we build CAML query in the text can be seen "FIELD VALUE" - it will be substituted namely the value of the item field over which runs a workflow?

Comment: @teylyn I understood. I thought it was possible to run the process on a particular folder, and then take the context folder, substitute its fields in the query. And start a workflow on each item returned. Apparently not.